# Timing/performance metrics of npm scripts

Tags: node.js, performance, build, gruntjs, npm

Is there a way to measure the performance of an npm scripts similar to the way [time-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-grunt) works?

I am moving some of my critical build tasks to use npm instead of Grunt as writing my own build script is more flexible than using some of the Grunt plugins like grunt-browserify for example.

I have tried using [`console.time()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label) but it finishes before the script is done, I assume because the methods are asynchronous. I also tried running the npm script as a Grunt task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('collectify', function () {
    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'npm',
        args: ['run', 'collectify:app']
    });
});
```

But the output is different than if I run `npm run collectify:app` from the command line, perhaps because of pwd issues.

Coloured bars would be nice but at the very least I'd like to see the time in numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried prepending the `time` command before your `npm run` command ?

So if your command is:

`npm run collectify:app`

It becomes:

`time npm run collectify:app`

And it'll output 3 lines e.g.

```
real    0m11.580s
user    0m7.400s
sys     0m1.304s
```

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is likely pre[foo] and post[foo] scripts.

So if I have a NPM script called "foobar" then I can create a script called "preboofar" and "postfoobar" and they will be executed automatically before and after "foobar" is executed.

So in "pre" you can touch a file with a timestamp and in "post" you can read that file and calculate the difference.